# 'Unable to create new session.' error using selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar with ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-server

For the past few days, I was running tests using Selenium WebDriver with no issues. However, even though I didn't change anything in the code or my system, the last few times I tried to create a new browser session, I always get the following error:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1kgd.png)

This happens regardless of whether I try to create a session through code, or manually through the browser.

This is the result of running the Selenium server and three tests:

```
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar 
05:54:58.659 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50'
05:54:58.660 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2019-04-18 05:54:58.754:INFO::main: Logging initialized @269ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
2019-04-18 05:54:58.821:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.7.v20170914, build timestamp: 2017-11-21T22:27:37+01:00, git hash: 82b8fb23f757335bb3329d540ce37a2a2615f0a8
2019-04-18 05:54:58.840:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@65d6b83b{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
2019-04-18 05:54:58.843:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@65d6b83b{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2019-04-18 05:54:58.859:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1de74ecb{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2019-04-18 05:54:58.859:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @374ms
05:54:58.859 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
2019-04-18 05:55:04.002:INFO:osjshC.ROOT:qtp527446182-17: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet-57175e74: Initialising WebDriverServlet
05:55:04.110 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.Status@4d5a702a
05:55:04.114 INFO - /status: Executing GET on /status (handler: Status)
05:55:04.178 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.GetAllSessions@3026be33
05:55:04.178 INFO - /sessions: Executing GET on /sessions (handler: GetAllSessions)
05:55:09.248 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@48e79260
05:55:09.249 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
05:55:09.333 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: chrome}
05:55:09.334 INFO - Capabilities {browserName: chrome} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706) on port 27011
Only local connections are allowed.
05:55:09.788 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
06:01:50.907 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@79d0ad1d
06:01:50.907 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@1ff85274
06:01:50.907 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@2d87d7a2
06:01:50.908 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
06:01:50.908 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
06:01:50.908 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
06:01:50.912 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: chrome}
06:01:50.912 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: chrome}
06:01:50.912 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: chrome}
06:01:50.912 INFO - Capabilities {browserName: chrome} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
06:01:50.912 INFO - Capabilities {browserName: chrome} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
06:01:50.912 INFO - Capabilities {browserName: chrome} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706) on port 29789
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706) on port 32366
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706) on port 15121
Only local connections are allowed.
06:01:51.271 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
06:01:51.335 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
06:01:51.449 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
```

I've tried downgrading, reinstalling everything, but nothing seems to work.

What I'm using:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Selenium Java Server 3.9.1
- Chrome 73
- Chrome Driver 74

Also, oddly enough, my colleague who similarly is working on Selenium with me, is now running into the exact same issue on their own system.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838878/4513879 hope its help you!!

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706) on port 15121
Only local connections are allowed.
06:01:51.271 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
```

...implies that your **ChromeDriver** version is *chromedriver=2.41*

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.41*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- Presumably you are using the latest GAed *chrome=73.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.46*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v71-73**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v73.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v71-73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it played a big role in helping us find a solution. The only part that was missing was that we needed to update our Selenium server version as well. Sorry for the late answer, and thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: @zzzz4 In your question heading you have explicitly mentioned about **Selenium Java Server 3.9.1** which should work as per my solution. Hence the answer. Else I would have suggested to upgrade to recent _Selenium v3.141.59_ as a generic suggestion. Glad to know your issue got resolved. Good luck.